# Is "profile" scope required for Google OAuth2.0?

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm currently trying to allow users of my application to authorize my app to access their Doubleclick for Advertisers API. I'm handling this authorization using [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/). When I include both the [profile scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) and DFA scope like this:

```
  app.get '/requestAccess', passport.authenticate 'dfa',
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking',
      'profile'
    ]
```

This works fine. However, I only care about the DFA api, and I don't actually intend on using anything from the profile scope, so I'd like to remove that:

```
  app.get '/requestAccess', passport.authenticate 'dfa',
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking',
    ]
```

When I authorize using this route now, I get:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Which comes from Google, meaning that the scope I requested with was insufficient. Is the profile scope required then for any kind of additional access? Why can't I only request the DFA scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the scope "profile" is not required for Google OAuth 2.0.

If you merely want the authorization for DFA API, you only need this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking`(as [official doc](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/docs/tasks?hl=cs) says, and [this java sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/) only use this scope)

The reason you get "Insufficient Permission" is when you use `passport.authenticate 'dfa'` authentication using an OAuth provider(in you case, it's Google) is performed, where the scope "profile" is required(as [this doc says](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes), "profile" is basic scope for login)